# Unknown table 'courses' in field even though the table actually exist in my database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, workbench

I have two tables, first one is courses table which saved course_id, course_name, course_time, credits... second is selected_course_list table which saved user's courses. The process is that user enter a course_id into Textfield and program will find out the correspond courses information(course_id, course_name, course_time...) then save into user's selected_course_list table.

However I use sql for insert course into select_course_list

The problem is: Actually I create a course table in my database, but the compiler show Unknown table 'courses' in field. Why? BTW, please help me to check whether my insert code is correct or not.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_project", "root","");
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO select_course_list(id,course_id,course_class,course_name,course_type,credit,class_time,max,selected) "
                            + "SELECT courses.id, courses.course_id, courses.course_class, courses.course_name, courses.course_type, courses.credit, courses.class_time, courses.max, courses.selected"
                            + "FROM courses  "
                            + "WHERE courses.course_id = "+course_code.getText()+" ";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
ps.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

The Compiler show:

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'courses' in field listjava.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'courses' in field list
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate, but there is another problem.

code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_project", "root","");

                      String sql1 = "INSERT INTO select_course_list(id,course_id,course_class,course_name,course_type,credit,class_time,max,selected) "
                              + "SELECT cs.id, cs.course_id, cs.course_class, cs.course_name, cs.course_type, cs.credit, cs.class_time, cs.max, cs.selected "
                              + "FROM courses cs "
                              + "WHERE cs.course_id  = "+course_code.getText()+"";  
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    ps.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

The output is

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''
```